# unable to send email. Emails are stuck in queue

Tags: exim

I am unable to send an email from server using exim.

When i try to send an email. email are stuck in queue

When i try to run exim -qff commands then emails are delivered. Other wise they just stay in queue and are not delivered.

Comment: Is there a question hidden in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on why the messages are being kept in the queue.
A check of */var/log/exim_mainlog* is recommended.

Try:

**/scripts/upcp --force**

**/scripts/eximup --force**

Comment: Can you please tell me about this  /var/log/exim_mainlog: Permission denied. i m logged in as root user

Answer (score 0):

For me - the issue was Load Average was too high and there was message:

```
2023-04-14 07:23:22 Abandon queue run: pid=18886 (load 655.15, max 12.00)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).